# Alternative to spawning a new thread to run a simple background task?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a button in my program's UI that calls a function which takes a lot time to execute. (`toggleLoveTrack()` in the example).

If I put that call directly on the JavaFX thread, the GUI freezes until the execution is complete.

So an alternative is to put the task in a separate background thread, execute that, and then update the UI using `Platform.runLater()` after the long executing function is complete, like this:

```
loveButton.setOnAction( ( ActionEvent e ) -> {
    Thread taskThread = new Thread (() -> {
        audioSystem.getLastFM().toggleLoveTrack( audioSystem.getCurrentTrack() );
        Platform.runLater( () -> updateLovedIndicator() );
    });
    taskThread.setDaemon( true );
    taskThread.start();
});
```

Is there a better way to do this than spawning a new thread every time the button is pressed? I think in this case it doesn't matter too much either way, but I'd like to do things The Better Way here if possible.

Comment: why are you making this a daemon thread?

Comment: I want the thread to termiante if the JVM would otherwise terminate -- it shouldn't keep the JVM alive.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not spawn a new thread for each task. Just create an [executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), store it as a field and submit each task as `runnable`.

```
// replace this with a thread pool executor or whatever
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Then, within your method:

```
executor.execute(() -> /* your code here */);
```

Better still, you can just use `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` and not care about the executor (the tasks will be submitted to the common fork/join pool unless you provide an explicit executor). This way, you'll get a [completable future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) result which allows you to add listeners and do any further processing.

Comment: In case of the `ExecutorService` it's important to shut it down when the application is done (e.g. from the `Application.stop` method) or use a `ThreadFactory` that creates deamon threads. Otherwise the JVM does not terminate properly.

Comment: Also note that since `Task` is a subclass of `FutureTask` and an implementation of `Runnable`, you can pass your `Task` instance to `executor.execute()`. This means you can still take advantage of the UI-specific `Task` lifecycle callbacks (`setOnSucceeded`, etc) while using it in the context of the `ExecutorService`.